# nginx proxy transfer to another server

Tags: nginx, webmail, nginx-reverse-proxy

Nginx server is at 192.168.5.13.
I have Nginx as reverse proxy for SSL Letsencrypt which works fine.
I would like to add ollowing:
www.nonprofitcloud.be is working fine and returns https://www.nonprofitcloud.be located  at 192.168.5.26.

However I would like to add webmail.nonprofitcloud.be to point to 192.168.5.1/mewebmail where my Mailenable Server is residing (Windows Server, IIS 7).

So: webmail.nonprofitcloud.be should point to 192.168.5.1/mewebmail

Any idea?

My conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.nonprofitcloud.be nonprofitcloud.be;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.nonprofitcloud.be/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.nonprofitcloud.be/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.5.26;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.nonprofitcloud.be nonprofitcloud.be;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `server` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name webmail.nonprofitcloud.be;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.5.1/mewebmail;
    }
}
```